# How can I refer to label created by new command?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have several pairs of graphs. I need to display these graphs in latex. I am using the following which works Great.

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{4-byVar1.png}}
    \caption{``Here's a question?'' (by Var1)}
    \label{fig:4-byVar1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{4-byVar2.png}}
    \caption{``Here's a question?'' (by Var2)}
    \label{fig:4-byVar2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{``Here's a question?''}
  \label{fig:comboFig-4}
\end{figure}
```

However, that's a lot of code to repeat for each such pair of figures. I created a

```
\newcommand
```

to do the work for me, but it seems that when I try to ref a figure created by my newcommand, i get an error (fig undefined).

**Can anyone recommend how I can refer to a label created by a newcommand?**

The newcommand I created looks like this

```
\newcommand{\graphPairs}[2]{
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{#2-byCar1.png}}
      \caption{#1 (by Var 1)}
      \label{fig:#2-byVar1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
      \centering
      \fbox{\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{#2-byVar2.png}}
      \caption{#1 (by Var 2)}
      \label{fig:#2-byVar2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{#1}
    \label{fig:comboFig-#2}
  \end{figure}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It does not matter, that `\label` is hidden in a `\newcommand`. For referencing you need the label name that depends on the second argument of `\graphPairs`. The first example would be generated by:

```
\graphPairs{``Here's a question?''}{4}
```

And the labels can be referenced by

```
\ref{fig:4-byVar1}
\ref{fig:4-byVar2}
\ref{fig:comboFig-4}
```

Answer (score 7):

TeX is a macro processor so it just does textual substitution of your command by its definition before `\label` is even considered. so if your command is called as

```
 \graphPairs{cap}{myfile}
```

Then your three `\label` are

```
\label{fig:myfile-byVar1}
```

and

```
\label{fig:myfile-byVar2}
```

and

```
\label{fig:comboFig-myfile}
```

so can be referenced as `\ref{fig:myfile-byVar1}`, `\ref{fig:myfile-byVar2}`, `\ref{fig:comboFig-myfile}`.

As always, it takes a couple of runs for references to be defined.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the "it takes a couple of runs" is what's holding me up. I had been using an IDE (sublime text 2 with mactex on a OS X) to build the PDF for me (so I have no idea what command to use and etc.). I tried running pdflatex mysourcefile.tex and that seemed to go ok, but even after running it a few times in a row, I am getting this warning: LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:comboFig-5' on page 25 undefined on input line 558. Any further suggestion?

Comment: `fig:comboFig-5` would correspond to calling your command with the 2nd argument being `{5}` so loading images `5-byCar1.png` and  `5-byVar1.png` is that what you did? it _always_ help if your question contains _complete_ runnable documents that demonstrate the problem.