# Is there a way to manage label indexes in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, labels

I am using TeXstudio for writing Latex papers. I have found that it is often troublesome to manage label indexes (for theorems, definitions, etc) such as whether an index has been used already and what indexes are available. This is especially important when copying content from other papers because some of the label indexes coincide with ones in the current paper.

TeXstudio is a good tex editor. So I expect that it should have a way to manage labels and I wonder how to do it in TeXstudio.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit in more detail or give us a MWE? In TeXstudio there is a left structure panel where the user can find for each file a list of labels in it, click and navigate between them. If a label is repeated, the default configuration is to highlight them with a different color (green to purple). Maybe you're looking for [strategies to name labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228022/label-naming-strategy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Basic use

In TeXstudio, the left structure menu display all LABELS in each file. You may easily navigate between labels by just clicking on the label. This example uses `equation`, but it applies to any label as far as I've used.

[image]

When a second identical label is inserted, both get purple.

[image]

---

### Side Note for `newcommands`

A side note I should add after remember some *not good practices* others colleagues did. Avoid using `\label` inside `\newcommand`. It is not impossible to do, but it will demand a little bit more effort than the necessary, since TeXstudio will note identify them at first.

[image]

And the autocomplete tool will not work properly without some extra trickery.

[image]

Please, also notice while creating `newcommand`s the formatting might vary.

[image]

To the correct identification, you will need to created your own `cwl`-files and take care with other possibles resources you might want in your document such as `hyperref`/`cleverref`. The basic suggestion is if you are **not** creating a long and complex document where you need to use many times the same set of instructions with labels, therefore a `newcommand`, just avoid anything more complex than the necessary.

---

### Links

The following links might be useful:

- [Parse a label defined inside a macro in TeXstudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/582890/parse-a-label-defined-inside-a-macro-in-texstudio)
- [How can I refer to label created by new command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84445/how-can-i-refer-to-label-created-by-new-command)
- [Auto label inside a new command definition for easing the usage of hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537600/auto-label-inside-a-new-command-definition-for-easing-the-usage-of-hyperref)
- [Own command for references - TexStudio does not recognize referenced labels](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467655/own-command-for-references-texstudio-does-not-recognize-referenced-labels)
- http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/texstudio/html/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION

---

### MWE for conference

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycmdlabel}[3][1]{
    \begin{table}
      \begin{tabular}{ll}
        #2
      \end{tabular}
      \caption{#3}
      \label{#1}
    \end{table}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:base}
  a = b + c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pitagoras}
  a^2 = b^2 + c^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:base} % repeated label
  c = a + b
\end{equation}
Table~\ref{tab:test}.
\mycmdlabel[tab:test]{
  a & b \\
  c & d}{Test 1}
\mycmdlabel[tab:test]{ % repeated label
  e & f \\
  g & h}{Test 2}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  a & b \\
  c & d \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. The color scheme of my print screens are the default of TeXstudio. Go in `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio...` -> `Syntax HIghlighting`. You may also load predefined styles and color schemes in the tab `General`.